# Wrapping text and changing column width in latex table

Tags: tables, columns

I recently asked for help in reducing the width of my tables to that of the text for my thesis. The answer worked perfectly for tables with lots of small columns but not ones containing lots of text. I am having trouble editing the code to reduce the width of the second column, wrapping the text and giving the third and fourth columns more space to reduce the overall height of the table. Can anyone help me with this please? I have included a reduced version of the code below.
Thanks in advance,
Holly

```
\begin{table}[h]
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l l *{7}{>{\hsize=0.95\hsize}x} >{\hsize=1.35\hsize}x @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{LFA}&\textbf{Lithofacies}&\textbf{Description}&\textbf{Interpretation}\\
\midrule
1&Massive lapilli tuffs (mLT)&Predominantly massive, well-sorted lithofacies with high proportion of juvenile fine ash matrix altered to chlorite and locally infilled by carbonates.&Mass wasting of maar-diatreme walls and deposition by gravity flows in an open crater; possible elutriation of ash from lower in the system.\\
1&Lapillistones (Lf)&Structureless and clast supported with small lapilli and a low proportion of matrix; juvenile bombs and large lithic clasts present. Localised ``raggy'' juvenile lapilli, preferred vertical orientation of clasts and apparent welding.&Fluidisation of hot lapilli in the central diatreme and transportation of outsized lithic clasts from lower in the stratigraphy\\
2&Bedded lapilli tuffs (bLT)&Highly heterogeneous lithofacies consisting of both massive and normally graded beds containing a high proportion of juvenile lapilli and highly variable proportion of fine ash matrix. Locally pockets of fine ash, pyrite and secondary calcite occur.&Subsided maar strata deposited near-vent as dilute density currents and later undercut by diatreme widening, leading to downward slumping along margins.\\
3&Massive lithic-rich lapilli tuffs (mlLT)&Structureless lithofacies locally with abundant lithic clasts and blocks, pervasive red-brown discolouration and fines-rich pockets and pipes.&Homogenous and structureless nature and degassing structures indicate fluidisation of diatreme fill.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption[Summary of diatreme lithofacies characteristics and interpretations]{Summary of lithofacies characteristics, context and interpretation for each lithofacies association in the diatremes}
\label{tb:Table 1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: your second `column` is `l` (single line flush left) you want to make it `p{1cm}` or `X` or something

Answer (score 1):

Is that more like you want?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[nomarginpar]{geometry}%,
 \usepackage{caption, booktabs}
 \usepackage{tabularx}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \footnotesize
  \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}\renewcommand\defaultaddspace{1.5ex}
  \captionsetup{font=small, labelfont=sc, format=hang}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c>{\hsize=0.65\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.30\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.05\hsize\arraybackslash} X @{}}
    %{@{} l l *{7}{>{\hsize=0.95\hsize}X} >{\hsize=1.35\hsize}X @{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{LFA} & \textbf{Lithofacies} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Interpretation} \\
    \midrule
    1 & Massive lapilli tuffs (mLT) & Predominantly massive, well-sorted lithofacies with high proportion of juvenile fine ash matrix altered to chlorite and locally infilled by carbonates. & Mass wasting of maar-diatreme walls and deposition by gravity flows in an open crater; possible elutriation of ash from lower in the system. \\
    \addlinespace
    1 & Lapillistones (Lf) & Structureless and clast supported with small lapilli and a low proportion of matrix; juvenile bombs and large lithic clasts present. Localised ``raggy'' juvenile lapilli, preferred vertical orientation of clasts and apparent welding. & Fluidisation of hot lapilli in the central diatreme and transportation of outsized lithic clasts from lower in the stratigraphy \\
    \addlinespace
    2 & Bedded lapilli tuffs (bLT) & Highly heterogeneous lithofacies consisting of both massive and normally graded beds containing a high proportion of juvenile lapilli and highly variable proportion of fine ash matrix. Locally pockets of fine ash, pyrite and secondary calcite occur. & Subsided maar strata deposited near-vent as dilute density currents and later undercut by diatreme widening, leading to downward slumping along margins. \\
    \addlinespace
    3 & Massive lithic-rich lapilli tuffs (mlLT) & Structureless lithofacies locally with abundant lithic clasts and blocks, pervasive red-brown discolouration and fines-rich pockets and pipes. & Homogenous and structureless nature and degassing structures indicate fluidisation of diatreme fill. \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption[Summary of diatreme lithofacies characteristics and interpretations]{Summary of lithofacies characteristics, context and interpretation for each lithofacies association in the diatremes}
  \label{tb:Table 1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works well thank you Bernard! I like the additional space between lines as well, makes it more readable